# Why Pipe doesn't work correctly in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

The task is simple, it is necessary that the input was entered only numbers below a certain number. I did so:

```
export class MaxNumber implements PipeTransform{
   transform(value, [maxNumber]) {
        value = value.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
        value = value > maxNumber?maxNumber:value;
        return value;
    }
}
```

and then in the template called something like:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="obj.count | maxNumber:1000" (ngModelChange)="obj.count=$event" />
```

But it works very strange [click](https://plnkr.co/edit/6VbiIZtAlbTmxihCC2uC?p=preview).

I probably misunderstand something. I would be grateful if someone will explain that behavior.

Comment: Why you don't use the type "number" and the attribute "max" ?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp

Comment: because I want to do that in angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need rather a custom value accessor. This way you will be able to check the value before setting it in the `ngModel`. This way you `obj.count` won't be upper than 1000.

Here is a sample implementation:

```
const CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => MaxNumberAccessor), multi: true});

@Directive({
  selector: 'input',
  host: {'(input)': 'customOnChange($event.target.value)'},
  providers: [ CUSTOM_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class MaxNumberAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    var normalizedValue = (value == null) ? '' : value;
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement,  'value', normalizedValue);
  }

  customOnChange(val) {
    var maxNumber = 1000;
    val = val.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
    val = val > maxNumber?maxNumber:val;
    this.onChange(val);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

There is nothing to do in your component to use it than setting this directive into its `directives` attribute:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      Number: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.count" />
      <p>Actual model value: {{obj.count}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MaxNumberAccessor]
})
export class App {
  (...)
}
```

Corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7e87xZoEHnnm82OYP84o?p=preview.